# Find numbers whose sum of digits is 7

Tags: php, numbers

i have a question that  i want to display the numbers up to 100 where the sum of their digits is 7.

can any one help me
suppos there is 25 . in ths 2+5=7 then it will be displayed. i have problem to break 25 as 2 and 5

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Try and improve the question and show us the code you have so far.

Comment: I assume you want numbers who's _digits_ add up to seven. Is that correct?

Comment: @Rajanikant: then you only want numbers up to 70, not up to 100.

Comment: u can say because after that no one will be found

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686881/algorithm-for-digit-summing

Answer (score 3):

I'm having a hard time to think why one would need such a program.

Anyways, 7 is one such number, next is 16, *clearly to get the same sum you need to increment the 10's digit by one and decrement ones digit by 1. So effectively you are incrementing the number by 9:*

```
for($i=7;$i<=70;$i+=9) {
        echo $i."\n";
}
```

Output:

```
7
16
25
34
43
52
61
70
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to write this without using the modulus operator(I know, no one would do that!!), you can take each number, split it into digits using preg_split and then find the sum of digits using array_sum:

```
for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++) {
        if(array_sum(preg_split('//',$i)) == 7)
                echo $i."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will do it. It uses mathematical knowledge that the first and last numbers that satisfy the condition are, respectively, `7` and `70`. It also knows that the next number in sequence is always nine more than the last:

```
for ($num = 7; $num <= 70; $num += 9)
    echo $num . "\n";
```

If you want to take an arbitrary two-digit number and sum the digits, you need an integer divide and modulo operator, such as:

```
25 div 10 -> 2
25 mod 10 -> 5
```

Integer division of `$x` by `$y` can be done in PHP with casting, while modulo uses the `%` operator.

A program giving the more adaptable case is shown below:

```
for ($num = 1; $num < 100; $num++) {
    $tens = (int)($num / 10);
    $ones = $num % 10;
    if ($tens + $ones == 7)
        echo $num . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's 7, 16, 25, 34, 43, 52, 61 and 70. Now you have the answer, so you don't need a program.

Comment: this i know but how can i do this in php

Answer (score 0):

There is a finite number of combinations as the answer to the question, and the list is small.  For example:

```
7,  0 + 7 = 7
16, 1 + 6 = 7
25, 2 + 5 = 7
34, 3 + 4 = 7
43, 4 + 3 = 7
52, 5 + 2 = 7
61, 6 + 1 = 7
70, 7 + 0 = 7
```

If you need it to be dynamic, and work for any number below 10 (e.g. 6), start with that number and add 9 to it, each time you do so up until `$num * 10` will give you the numbers you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

well you could always use the following code to generate numbers up to any limit

all variables are integers

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
    //where n is the upper limit.In this case it is 100
    n=i;

    while(n!=0){

        d=n%10;// to extract the last digit

        s=s+7;//  to calculate sum of digits

        n=n/10;// to remove the last digit

    }

    if(s==7)

    System.out.println(+i);

}//close for loop
```

Comment: Please make sure you speak in proper English and also format your code